# Using jsp in Reactjs app

Tags: html, jsp, reactjs

I have 2 questions which are related:

1.) I have a react app, which is loading using index.html
Can I do this index.html as index.jsp? When I simply change it like that, then run my npm server, go to localhost:8080/index.jsp, then this file doesn't open but downloads it.

2.) Can I simply run a jsp file in an npm server?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can use React in a HTML page rendered from any source, including JSP.
2. No. This is why your attempt at 1) failed - JSP are **Java** Server Pages. You need a Java application server to execute JSP and serve the HTML output.

Comment: So, can I run Tomcat and npm server at the same time? It doesn't let me, it seems.

Comment: The thing is I want some output from the jsp and want to use it in my react app.

Comment: Maybe because both are running on localhost:8080?? Then how I change the port in that case for either?

Comment: The port should be in the code, config or command you use to launch your node server. Grep for `8080` maybe?

Comment: I found it in server.xml of tomcat installation. But can I pass a variable from a jsp file(running on tomcat) to a js file (running on npm server)? Both are in the same folder.